# KivyMD: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' during screen transition based on condition

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to switch from login screen to menu screen based on a successful authentication, but this is the best I could do after a long search on condition-based screen transitions. Most sites say that screen-transitions in kivymd should be done using 'on-release' in .kv file, but I don't think that it would work in my code.

I've marked on the code the problematic line, which is raising the exception.

**Teste.py**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class login(Screen):
    pass
class menu(Screen):
    pass

Builder.load_file('lteste.kv')
class LoginApp(MDApp):
    dialog = None
    def build(self): #método construtor da parte visual do aplicativo
        
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Indigo"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Blue"

        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(login(name="login"))
        self.sm.add_widget(menu(name="menu"))
        self.sm.current = "menu"
        return self.sm
    
    def dialog_box(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Log In",
                text=f"Welcome {self.root.ids.user.text}!",
                buttons=[MDFlatButton(text="Ok", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                                      on_release=self.close),],)
        return self.dialog.open()
    
    def login(self):
        if self.root.ids.user.text=='1' and self.root.ids.password.text=='1':
            self.sm.current = "menu" #<- problem
            self.dialog_box()
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def close(self, instance):
        self.dialog.dismiss()
        

LoginApp().run()
```

**lteste.kv**

```
<login>:
    id: login
    name: "login"
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 300, 600
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 65
        spacing: 35
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDIcon:
            icon: 'account'
            icon_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            halign: 'center'
            font_size: 180
        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: user
            icon_left: "account-check"
            hint_text: "Usuário"
            foreground_color: 1, 0, 1, 1
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 220
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: password
            icon_left: "key-variant"
            hint_text: "Senha"
            foreground_color: 1, 0, 1, 1
            size_hint_x: None
            height: 1
            width: 220
            font_size: 20            
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            password: True
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "ENTRAR"
            font_size: 15
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            on_press: app.login()
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "REGISTRAR-SE"
            font_size: 15
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
<menu>
    name: "menu"
    id: menu
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 300, 600
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 65
        spacing: 35
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Test"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application `root` does not contain the `ids` you want. They are in the `login` screen widget because you defined them under it in kivy language. It would help to store a reference on the login screen to access them. Replace

```
        self.sm.add_widget(login(name="login"))
```

with

```
        self.login_screen = login(name="login")
        self.sm.add_widget(self.login_screen)
```

Then, you can access the widgets like so,

```
                text=f"Welcome {self.login_screen.ids.user.text}!",
```

and

```
        if (self.login_screen.ids.user.text=='1'
            and self.login_screen.ids.password.text=='1'):
```

There is an example in the Kivy Documentation on [`kivy.uix.widget.Widget.ids`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=ids#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.ids) and also [Accessing Widgets defined inside Kv lang in your Python code](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code).